# Dynamically allocating an array of 'Vector' class

Tags: c++, oop

So i have to implement a 'Matrix' abstract class that uses an array of pointers to 'Vector' as its content. 
'Square_matrix' is the actual implementation of Matrix.

```
class Vector
{
    int dim;  // dimension
    int* a;   // actual array
public:
    Vector(int n)
    {
        dim = n;
        a = new int[n];
    }

};

class Matrix     //it will be an abstract class
{
protected:
    Vector* v;
public:
    Matrix(int col, int lin)
    {
        //here is my problem
    }
};

class Square_matrix : public Matrix
{
    int dim;
public:
    Square_matrix(int dim) 
        : Matrix(dim, dim) { this-> dim = dim; }
};
```

How can i make something like this work?

```
Matrix(int lin, int col)
{
   v = new (Vector*)[lin];
   for(int i = 0; i < lin; i++)
   {
       v[i] = new Vector(col);
   }
}
```

Comment: If you're not able to use smart pointers instead of raw pointers, you definitely need to provided destructors for your classes. Also, you need to decide if your matrix is built from column vectors or row vectors.

Comment: It is build out of row vectors. I provided destructors but didn't paste them here because I didn't think it was necessary. I want to know how to make a dynamic array of Vectors and store it in the Matrix object

Comment: StackExchange123 you had the right idea. You just needed to add Rule of Three (and Rule of Five for better performance) support to `Vector` in your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course using `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` is probably not what you want to do ;D.

Regarding problem in your code --- you keep integers in Vector:

```
int* a; // int a[];
```

and  you keep Vectors in Matrix

```
Vector* v; // Vector v[]
```

but in your constructor you try to allocate new vector each time, so to be consistent you should actually add one star in declaration of v:

```
Vector** v; // Vector* v[];
...
Matrix(int lin, int col)
{
   v = new Vector*[lin];
   for(int i = 0; i < lin; i++)
   {
       v[i] = new Vector(col);
   }
}
```

Alternatively, you may use a bit more complicated solution, keep declaration of v as it is there for now and use placement new:

```
Vector* v; // Vector v[]
...
Matrix(int col, int lin) // what if somebody mixes order of col and lin?
{
        // watch out for alignment if you do such tricks!!!
        v = reinterpret_cast<Vector*>(new char[sizeof(Vector)*lin]);
        for(int i = 0; i < lin; i++)
        {
                new (v+i) Vector(col);
        }
}
```

Of course, don't forget about destructors, exception safety, and so on...

Comment: I used the more complicated solution. Now in order to free the memory is it okay to do this? `for(int i = 0; i < lin; i++) (v+i) -> ~Vector();`

Comment: @AndreiTudose Beacause we did reinterpret_cast calling ```delete[] v``` may not do what we really want (it segfaults on my computer :). So basically yes, you need to call destructor manually ```v[i].~Vector();```, and then call ```delete[] reinterpret_cast<char*>(v);```

Comment: And for alignment you may want to look at std::aligned_storage (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage)